# RxJava compare different items by id from two observables

Tags: rx-java

I have two Observables (`O1 & O2`) that emit items of different types. If `A.Id` is contained in `O1` I want to ignore `A*.sameId` from `O2`. The best solution I came up with so far is to load all Ids from `O1` into a Set first (waiting for `onComplete() or blocking` ). Then I load the elements from `O2` and compare them one-by-one with the `O2 Set` with `filter()`.

What is the best (most elegant) way to express this just with operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the complete set from O1 to check values of O2:

```
o1.collect(HashSet::new, (a, b) -> a.add(b))
.flatMap(set -> o2.filter(v -> !set.contains(v)))
...
```

Comment: correct and more concise code: .collect(HashSet::new, HashSet::add)